# How to align buttons from vertical to horizontal in Bootstrap dependent on device viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my [website](http://sti.gy), I have a set of buttons aligned vertically using the following;

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 5%;
    width: 120px;}

.sidebar .icons {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 21px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<section class="sidebar">
    <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
    <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
    <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
</section>
```

The background image and center image of the site both adjust responsively however,
these buttons stay vertical and do not scale causing a large blank area when viewed on mobile devices.

How can I use Bootstrap to make these buttons align horizontally along the top of the page
when viewed on a mobile device?

Comment: do you look at @media of css?

Comment: If you would look at the components section of BootStrap you'll see various items you can use.  One of which being navs, as well as Button Groups, etc...It will give you everything you need to know via Documentation in order to use this item on the page.  Generally Navigation Items and other components are all built to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I am not sure whether I've understood it correctly, but since you're using bootstrap you can do it this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="animation"><a href=""><img class="icons" src=""></a></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```